# Why won't my Discord Bot send me a message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I decided to start developing my own Discord bot in NodeJS.
I wanted to write a simple example. I created a code that should make the bot respond to the "hello" message. The Discord bot works, but it does not respond to hello. I have been trying for hours..

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
const token = '';

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === 'hello') {
        msg.reply('Hello!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because new discord's privacy policy.

1. You have to enable **messages content intent** in discord developers. [image: discord developers]
2. You need to add **messages content intent** in code.

```js
  const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ Discord.GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, Discord.GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent ] });
```